# How long can a can a container of unopened hummus be left out?

Tags: food-safety, hummus

I have a container of Sabra hummus (garlic, for those judging my decision making abilities) that I left out for about 14 hours today. The container still has the plastic seal inside the lid unopened.

Cooked chickpeas, oil, and tahini are the main ingredients but I don't have the full ingredient list. How long could this sit out and still be good?

Comment: I've read that wiki before, and I don't think it answers my question. It seems highly unlikely to me that cooked chickpeas in a safety sealed container would go bad in 2 hours as that answer suggests.